# Divs and image not scaling, responsiveness

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

the div:preview-movie not taking the rest of the width.

the itunes div overscaling on big screens.

on small screens how can the logo div get smaller and the details-movie div go under.

Thanks

HTML CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page-movie-x</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page-film.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="15">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <p>
            menu dropdown
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="logo">
            <div class="movie-name">
                A Name 
            </div>
            <img class="Itunes-link" src="http://dxm2idf2u6bml.cloudfront.net/rest/serve/THUMBNAILS/55b856e3-c26f-416f-ac65-c588230582ee.jpg" >

            <div class="date-out">
                Date de sortie : / / 
            </div>

            <div class="rating">
                <span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span><span>☆</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="details-movie">
            <div class="description-movie">

            </div>
            <div class="preview-movie">
                <iframe  class="youtube-vid" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/eEZ0u9xI2yo"  ></iframe>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
.container{
  display:flex;

}
.dropdown-menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5vh;
    background-color: blue;
}

.logo{
    max-width: 300px;
    height: 100vh;

    background-color: red;
}

.details-movie{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vh;
    background-color: grey;


}
.movie-name{background-color: yellow;}
.Itunes-link{
    height: 30%;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    background-color: green;
}

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.rating > span:hover:before {
   content: "\2605";
   position: absolute;
}

.description-movie{height:32%;
    background-color: white;
}
.preview-movie{
    display: flex;
    width: 100vh;
}
.preview-movie .youtube-vid{
justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing all the code that is actually needed to solve the problem!

Here's a couple of things that may help:

1) You've used `width: 100vh;` in both `.details-movie` and `.preview-movie`. vh is based on the height, not the width. You want the inner div (`.preview-movie`) to be `width: 100%`, and then only manipulate the width of the parent. You *may* want `width: 100vw` on the parent, but it would be more sensible to give both `.details-movie` and `.logo` a percentage-based width. That way both will scale responsively. Just remember to ensure that the two divs add to a total of 100%!

2) I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "the itunes div overscaling on big screens", but I assume that you're talking about the image getting stretched. It already *has* a max-width, so it will never escape those bounds (300px). Simply replace `height: 30%` with `width: 100%`. That will ensure the picture won't get hidden, and will also make it retain its proportions.

3) For your third point, I'm also not quite sure what you mean. I believe you want to decrease the size of the logo and put the `.details-movie` div 'underneath' on smaller screens. That can be done with a media query:

```
@media (max-width: 900px) { // Whatever size you'd like to affect
   .logo {
        width: 66px; // Whatever size changes you'd like 
    }
    .container {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I've made a fiddle where you can see these changes over at https://jsfiddle.net/Lnr2tt37/. There's still a lot of work to be done, but hopefully the changes reflect the points you've raised in this question. The rest is up to you to work out ;)

Hope this helps!

EDIT AFTER COMMENT:

1) To fix the problem of `nav` not taking up the full width on mobile devices, you can simply add:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    body > div > nav {
        flex: 100%;
    }
}
```

600 pixels looks about right to me, but you may need to adjust that breakpoint.

2) To ensure that both `nav` and `main` take up the full vertical height, you could use something like the following:

```
@media (min-width: 601px) { // One pixel more than the max-width breakpoint
    body > div > nav {
        min-height: 100vh;
    }
```

Note that you'll only want this to happen when `nav` and `main` are next to each other, as otherwise `nav` will become massive!

3) To ensure that the YouTube video (iframe) takes up full width, you just need to give it a width of 100%. Not that you'll probably want to give it a height as well, for better display. Unfortunately, the way that iframes work makes it incredibly difficult to make them responsive, so you will *always* get a bit of a black bar at certain widths. This height seems to work pretty well for me, but you may want to adjust it:

```
iframe {
   width: 100%;
   height: 344px;
}
```

I've updated the fiddle to reflect this, and the changes can be found over at https://jsfiddle.net/Lnr2tt37/2/.

Hopefully this all helps :)

Comment: Hello mate, thanks for the reply i changed the though here is a new code ive done , everything is responsive, except on small screens the nav doesnt take full width, and the elements on big screens dont take full lenght of the page.And last question do you have idea in addapting the youtube video ?  https://jsfiddle.net/Lnr2tt37/1/  thanks

Comment: The changes you've made are a massive improvement! Well done! I've updated my answer to hopefully address the three problems you've pointed out there. Simply check the second half of my answer :)

Comment: @media is for media queries. They apply CSS rules at specific screen resolutions. You just specify the widths you want to affect, as above. In your example, you want to do different things for small screens and large screens, so you need a media query. The more precise you want to be, the more media queries you will need. There's a couple of frameworks that are *built* around media queries, such as Bootstrap and Foundation, which handle all of the hard work for you. It may be worthwhile looking into those :)

Comment: as i'm doing this i'm gonna try with time to create my own personnal styled framework cause all websites are starting to look alike :d thanks again mate great help

Comment: No worries! Although I really do recommend you look into something like Bootstrap though. Not all websites that use it look alike; it simply gives you more control over responsiveness. For example, it can automatically shift elements below one another when viewed on a tablet or mobile. There's need to worry about media queries! There's lots of customisability, and on top of everything, it's both free and easy to use. Some examples can be found at http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/. If you choose to make your own framework, that's great, but you'd be essentially reinventing the wheel ;)